# how can I change the Predefined variables in vscode json file

Tags: visual-studio-code

for example:
when I run the tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
     {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}\\bulid\\${relativeFileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
     }        
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

it print

```
C:\Users\***\OneDrive\***\CLion\bulid\CourseBook\0201_SqList\SqList-main.exe
```

because my filename was SqList-main.c.

But what I want is Sqlist.exe.
Can I do something to let it print?

```
C:\Users\***\OneDrive\***\CLion\bulid\CourseBook\0201_SqList\SqList.exe
```

I want a smart or auto method because I have many files to change.

tips: the .c file can not rename for some reason.

Comment: what are your other file names and what needs to be removed

Answer (score 1):

Using extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.6.0 there is a command that can transform a number of variables.

For this case you have to modify `task.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
     {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo ${workspaceFolder}\\build\\${relativeFileDirname}\\${input:noMain}.exe"
     }        
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "noMain",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "find": "-main"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use any regular expression as `find` and define a `replace` string with capture group references (`$1`), and the `flags` to use to construct the regular expression.